# Django Regex URL pattern overriding other URLs

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a project which requires to display the data about a city which is requested through the url like example.com/city1 for city1 information etc.

I have used the below url pattern & view in my app. This view is working fine.

`url(r'^(?P<cityId>[-\w]+)$',views.cityindex,name='cityindex'),`

```
def cityindex(request, cityId):
    city = City.objects.filter(url = cityId)
    if len(city) == 0:
        return redirect('/404')
    return HttpResponse('City Data Extracted')
```

But when I try to open other urls like `/admin` or urls from other app it is being redirected to my `cityindex` view and then to 404 page as handled in my view above.

Below is the url patterns I used in my main urls.py file.

`url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'^login_redirect/', include('loginapp.urls')),`

I am presently using Django 1.11.12. Is there any way to stop this url from overriding?

Edit :
Urls in my main.urls file

```
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
url(r'^about$', views.aboutpage,name="aboutpage"),
url(r'^terms$', views.termspage,name="termspage"),
url(r'^privacy$', views.privacypage,name="privacypage"),
url(r'^(?P<cityId>[-\w]+)$',views.cityindex,name='cityindex'),
```

Comment: Can you try again by adding `$` like ` url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls),
`

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Not working.
`NoReverseMatch at /admin/
Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'main'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/$(?P<app_label>main|auth|error_report)/$']`

Comment: PLease research on this. May be url regex related problem

Comment: @SunilTatipelly the url declaration order is important, place your custom regex url at the bottom

Comment: You should show the contents of main.urls.

Comment: @BasilJose those urls are already at the bottom.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added it to the question.

Comment: I guess you forgot to give a '/' before the $ sign in your url. Copy paste this and see, url(r'^(?P<cityId>[-\w]+)/$',views.cityindex,name='cityindex'),

Comment: give the / before the $ sign for all your urls in urls.py

Comment: @SammyJ tried it, not working.

Comment: Hi @SunilTatipelly I guess you are trying to query a city right, so why not add city/ , give this in `url(r'^city/(?P<cityId>[-\w]+)$',views.cityindex,name='cityindex')`,then give www.example.com/city/<city_id>/ in the browser, currently I guess it is hitting the home page and looking for the city ID instead of other pages

Comment: Currently i am working using the /city/cityid url but the client requirement is that it must be /cityid similar to instagram user profile url which is /username.

Comment: Ok got it so you always get the city ID on www.example.com/<city_id>. So why not convert the index view that you have and let it render the city data in that page, what I mean is put the city querying code into index, if you get city_ID, render that city else do some other operation.I haven't tested this, but give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, think of sceanarios like this

```
1- www.example.com/cityname/  
2- www.example.com/about/Us/
3- www.example.com/others/terms/ 
4- www.example.com/others/privacy/
```

> Anytime you want to have other url like www.example.com/faculty/list
>   you use **number 2-4** while you use the first to achieve your city name.

I have tested this to work in the following format

```
 urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^about/us/$', views.about_page), #about us or any other page
        url(r'^(?P<cityname>\w+)/$', views.cityindex), #cityname


    ]
```

and in my view.py, i can catch the city name given like this

```
def cityindex(request, cityname):
    data = cityname
    #you can do anything you want here
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

NB: the cityname could a number so you may decide to use it as city id instead, however, ensure it was converted to an integer in your view if you prefer to use cityid

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey Akinniyi, Thanks for the answer. I have tried this but my client requirement is that it should be only /cityid or /cityname similar to instagram user profile url which is /username.

I am thinking maybe in my cityindex function instead of directly redirecting it to 404 page when the City doesn't exists, I should make it to check for other urls in the home. Do you know of any workaround of anything similar?

Comment: I have updated my answer to match with what you said, kindly check and feed me back